# Route resolve promise, not fully resolved - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-promise

So, what I'm trying to do here is something simple:

1. check the role of the loggedUser on each route (with a resolve that sets the user if a token or login credentials are valid on the backend)
2. redirect to the intended route
3. if not allowed for a route, redirect to a different route

In my route provider I have something like

```
$routeProvider
  ...
  .when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'views/admin/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'AdminDashboardCtrl',
    resolve: {
      checkLoggedUser: check
    }
  })
  ...
```

where ckeck is this function

```
var check = function($rootScope, $q, AuthService) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  if($rootScope.loggedUser) {
    return;
  }

  console.log('inside resolve check')

  AuthService.check().success(function(data) {
    $rootScope.loggedUser = data.user;
    deferred.resolve(data.user);
  });

  console.log('finished check')

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

And my AuthService.check() is this function

```
check: function()
  {
    var authtoken = StorageService.get('authtoken');
    if(!authtoken) {
      $location.path('login');
    }

    console.log('before returning');

    return $http.post($rootScope.base + 'auth/authenticate', { 'authtoken': authtoken });
  },
```

In my .run(function I have

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  setIntendedUrl();
  console.log($rootScope.loggedUser);
  console.log($location.path());
});
```

and setIntendedUrl() check for the loggedUser and redirects to the correct page (or, in what I'm trying to accomplish, redirect to a different page if not allowed, for example the loggedUser has role = 1, can visit only the routes /admin, if a user has role = 2, and the requested path is /admin, he has to be redirected to /user)

So after all this code, when the app run this is my log in the console (see in the code where are they called)

```
inside resolve check app.js:29
before returning authservice.js:24
finished check app.js:36
intended: /admin/agents/create app.js:149 <--- here is where I redirect the user
Object {id: "21", name: "Kyle", surname: "Butler", roleId: "2"...} app.js:167
/admin/agents/create <--- requested path
```

This is not what I was expecting, so the first three logs are good, the third doesn't wait the promise to be returned (so I don't have a loggedUser) then the AuthService:check() returns the user and it's everything done at this point, the user with role = 2 is in a route that is not allowed to see.

Just to complete the code, this is the setIntendedUrl function

```
var setIntendedUrl = function() {
  intended = $location.path();
  console.log('intended: ' + intended)
  if(intended !== '/login') {
    if($rootScope.loggedUser && $rootScope.loggedUser.roleId === '1' &&  !/^\/admin*/.test(intended)) {
      intended = '/admin';
    } else if($rootScope.loggedUser && $rootScope.loggedUser.roleId === '2' &&  !/^\/manager*/.test(intended)) {
      intended = '/manager';
    }
    StorageService.set('intended', intended);
    //$location.path(intended);
  }
};
```

What I am doing wrong? Why the user in the check function is not resolved before the other code is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make use of session/locals storage or $rootScope where you can store the users authorization object with  given routes, permission info once user logged in.

Now is route resolve or run() block you can retrieve the user auth object perform authorization action.

e.g.

```
.run(['sessionService', '$rootScope', '$location', function(sessionService, $rootScope, $location) {
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    var currentUser = sessionService.get('user_details');

    if(next.taskAccess && next.taskAccess != ""){
        var hasPerm = $rootScope.getPermission(next.taskAccess);
        if(!hasPerm){
             $location.path('/unauthorized');
        }
    }
});
```

}]);

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your code, why do I have to take from local data the logged user details if I ask just before to the server to authenticate the user (and to send me the details)? this is also too easy to break and gain access to not allowed routes, just open the console and set/change the value in the local data. I also do not understand what is taskAccess and where is set. Sorry about that, can you try to explain it better, please?